# C++ istream runs forever

Tags: c++, iostream, istream

I'm a begineer and am disappointed at how am i still not getting it.
I need help please..

```
MAIN==
    ifstream infile("new.txt");
    if (!infile) return -1;

    Class classObj;
    infile >> classObj;
```

```
Class.h
    public:
        friend istream& operator>>(istream & input, Class cObj);
```

```
Class.cpp
    istream& operator>>(istream & input, Class cObj){

    string temp;
    while(temp!="TEST6"){
        getline(input, temp, ',');
        if(temp=="TEST1") cObj.setA(temp);
        if(temp=="TEST3") cObj.setB(temp);
        if(temp=="TEST5") cObj.setC(temp);
        if(temp=="TEST6") cObj.setD(temp);
    }

    return input;
}
```

```
new.txt==

TEST1,TEST2,TEST3,TEST4,TEST5,TEST6
```

I am some random text sorry

Comment: Given your example text, how would `temp` ever be a string of just a single `T`?

Comment: My bad.. i want to end it after i found the string "TEST6"

Comment: You should combine these two lines `while(temp!="TEST6"){
        getline(input, temp, ',');` into `while (temp!="TEST6" && getline(input, temp, ',')) {`

Comment: Quick test seems to work: https://ideone.com/cmFrr9

Comment: @JohnnyMopp! interesting! yes, it does, but when i change it to ifstream TEST6 doesnt appear and program keeps going.: [

Comment: Is there a white space after "TEST6" (like a space or newline)? If so, that would cause your error.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i thought the same, but i checked on the text file, there is no whitespace or newline.

Comment: I would still say the code is flawed if it does not exit the loop when the stream is at the end regardless of whether or not TEST6 is in the input or not.